# Storyboard scene not displaying in Xcode9

Tags: ios, storyboard, editor, preview, xcode9

Updated to Xcode 9 and now some of my storyboard scenes are blocked out as shown below, and won't display in preview.  I can select the controls but obviously editing is severely impaired.   Based on related posts I tried cleaning the project, deleting derived data, and setting the interface builder document "Opens in" to the earlier version of Xcode, all with restarts.  No results.

I've seen Xcode do this before but the issue has worked itself out quickly.

Any other ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's helpful for you In XCode 9:
Editor > canvas > show Bounds rectangles. This option show/hide the blue lines.

> after that save project.
>
> close the XCode.
>
> open the project files.